# Safari bug using CSS transform property in keyframe animation

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I'm trying to animate a SVG graphic with keyframes, but my animation doesn't work correctly in Safari.  It's fine in Chrome and Firefox, but Safari doesn't seem to render it the way I'd like it to.  I'm using the `-webkit-` vendor prefix on my CSS properties, but that doesn't seem to help.  I have no idea what could be causing such a thing.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewKosloski/x2m5Lbd1/) is a Fiddle link to my code.

Here is what the problem looks like:

[image]

Here is a snippet of one of the keyframes:

```
@-webkit-keyframes dropOne {
    0%, 100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(6px, -6px);
    }
    25%, 50%, 75% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
}
```

Comment: What Safari version are you using, I'm on Safari 9 and it works fine for me.

Comment: @LeonAves Ohh, I'm on Safari 8.  I don't want to update to El Capitan, though.

Comment: Can't help you then I'm afraid! Let me know if you work it out though, can't see why it wouldn't work. Have you tried: removing the duplicate keyframe declarations, so getting rid of the first declaration and putting opacity: 0; in the second and third?